# Outer loop to loop over each row and nested loop to loop over each character

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested-loops, outer-join

I have to write a static method called "count" taking a char as parameter that will return the number of times that this char occurs in Layout.ROWS (array of strings in class Layout). To do that I need an outer loop to loop over each row and nested loop to loop over each character. This is what I tried:

```
public static int count(char d)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    int i = 0;

     while ( i < Layout.ROWS.length && !Layout.ROWS[i].equals(d) ) 
     {  
         i++;

         if (Layout.ROWS[i].equals(d))
         {
            sum++;
         }
     }   

     return sum;
}
```

But it is not working. My output is:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Any idea of how I should do it?
This is Layout.ROWS:

```
public static final String[] ROWS = {
    "     p      ex",
    " .            ",
    "  .           ",
    "   .          ",
    "    .         "
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: This is my output:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to compare a string (`Layout.ROWS[i]`) to a `char`. You should iterate over the `String`s in your array, and for each such `String` iterate over the `char`s that make it up. While this can be acheived with a `while` loop, using `for` loops would be much cleaner:

```
public static int count(char d) {
    int sum = 0; 

    // Iterate over all the strings in Layout.ROWS:
    for (String str : Layout.ROWS) {
        // Iterate over the chars of the string:
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
            if (d == str.charAt(i)) {
                ++sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```